# UFW is blocking all even when I set rules to allow

Tags: firewall, ufw

I am using an ubuntu server, Now I am trying to enable the firewall using these commands:

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default allow outgoing

ufw allow ssh
ufw allow www
ufw allow https

ufw enable
```

I've also tried making the `ufw default deny incoming` the last one but still no luck, when I enable the firewall it blocks eveything when I set the default to deny, but when I set it to allow, it works well, like the rules are ignored.
what could be causing this ?

### EDIT

This is my output of `iptables -L -v -n`
I also tried the proposed solution but still no luck, it works fine **only** when I make it `default allow incoming`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 30 packets, 1764 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 104 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
    0     0 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Can you do me a favor?  Do `ufw enable`, then paste the output of `sudo iptables -L -v -n` to your question.  I'm curious what the underlying `netfilter`/`iptables` stuff is actually doing with the ufw rules.  :)

Comment: The first two commands are unnecessary. All you need to do is enable UFW and the default deny in allow out will apply.

Comment: Oooh, mchid is right, those're the defaults, you don't need those.  Having said that, I still want to see the `iptables` data if, with those first two lines excluded, you are still having this issue.

Comment: I added the output of my iptables file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

Start off by doing a reset, which will remove all the existing rules:

```
sudo ufw reset
```

Next,

```
sudo ufw app list
```

This will list the available application profiles, such as, OpenSSH and others. To get info on an app, type the following command like in this example:

```
sudo ufw app info OpenSSH
```

Here's the output:

```
Profile: OpenSSH
Title: Secure shell server, an rshd replacement
Description: OpenSSH is a free implementation of the Secure Shell protocol.

Port:
  22/tcp
```

To allow OpenSSH access, you can use the following rule:

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Unlike Debian, www and https are not usually included as app profiles, however, we know these operate on ports 80 and 443 so use the following commands:

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

If you want to add UDP just do this as well.

```
sudo ufw allow 80/udp
sudo ufw allow 443/udp
```

Disable and enable ufw to apply the changes:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

To show your rules:

```
sudo ufw status
```

Finally, one of the less friendly aspects of ufw is how the deny rules usually trump allow rules. For example, you cannot set everything to deny and then set ports to allow. All ports will still be blocked. [See here for more info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893751).

---

You can add these rules to globally block all ports except 22, 53, 80, and 443. I've added port 53 to allow DNS requests. If you don't need to make DNS queries, just modify the rules accordingly.

To set these block rules for incoming only, you would use `sudo ufw deny in 1:22/tcp` for example. Alternatively, set for outgoing `sudo ufw deny out 1:22/tcp` and so on.

```
sudo ufw deny 1:21/tcp
sudo ufw deny 1:21/udp
sudo ufw deny 23:52/tcp
sudo ufw deny 23:52/udp
sudo ufw deny 54:79/tcp
sudo ufw deny 54:79/udp
sudo ufw deny 81:442/tcp
sudo ufw deny 81:442/udp
sudo ufw deny 444:65535/tcp
sudo ufw deny 444:65535/udp
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, but I want to block all the ports except for those ones, should I use `ufw default block incoming` after setting those rules ?

Comment: @Developer106 No, when you enable ufw, block incoming is already set to default. You can verify this by executing the following command in an open terminal `sudo ufw status verbose`. If I'm not mistaken, explicitly setting that rule will not permit your allowed ports. If you want to block all ports except those, I really suggest you check out this thread as that's exactly what they do. It is very thorough, blocking all except those and you'll have the open ports you want. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893751

Comment: @Developer106 I added some rules to globally block all except 22, 53, 80, and 443 and deny or block every other port.

Comment: ok it only works when specify to deny `out` if I say `deny` without saying that it is for out specifically, it still doesn't work. what could be the cause of that ?

Comment: @Developer106 what doesn't work, is it not blocking or not allowing?

Comment: it is not allowing, meaning that when I set the deny on the incoming it does not work, but for outgoing it works fine

Comment: @engma did you solve the problem. I came across this question and I am sure that the reason is because `iptables` does not reflect the change in `ufw` anymore. So no matter how much you reset `ufw`, flush and add rules, it would never work. FixItDad below mentioned this strange behavior, seems like a conflict between `ufw` and `iptables` especially when you flush the `ufw` from `iptables` before.

Comment: The lightbulb moment for me was when you said, "...deny rules usually trump allow rules."  With that in mind, I reconfigured ufw and got everything working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

FYI: in case others have this problem.

In the detailed iptables output I noticed the ufw rules are missing in the INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD chains. My system ended up like this when I ran iptables -F to remove my custom FW rules after enabling ufw at some point. It appears that ufw does not add the top level rules back in if some of its own chains already exist in iptables.

I ended up un-installing ufw, rebooting, ran 'iptables -F' (to remove previous iptables rules that were still active), then reinstalling and configuring ufw. The top level ufw rules are now back. The uninstall /reinstall may not have been necessary. Just removing all ufw rules from iptables by disabling ufw and rebooting may have done the trick.

Here's what the top level chains should look like (on Debian 9.4).

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me also.

Comment: Running `iptables -X` in order to delete all non-builtin chains and then restarting `ufw` also worked for me.

Comment: @Tblue thanks for this tip (5 years later,) seems to be the easiest way to fix things. Took me an hour to identify the root cause, but an easy fix after that. I wonder, is this a bug in ufw or is the blame on the user (me, I suppose) for having made a change manually to the iptables rules at some point?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, some kind of screwed config with `ufw` and `fail2ban` messed up the iptables chain. Everything was blocked as soon as I started ufw - even with no rules in the `ufw` chain itself. `ufw` reset did not help. I completely reinstalled it, this worked out.

```
sudo apt-get purge ufw
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

Comment: Hi Maso. Did you have to do any additional configuration after reinstalling?

Answer (score 2):

#### The reason in my case

After digging in for a while, I found out the direct reason why `ufw allow` not taking effect.

##### The issue is in the iptables.

[image]

- The rule **REJECT all** in **INPUT** is above the chain reference **ufw-before-input**.
- And the exact rule created by `ufw allow` is locate in chain **ufw-user-input**.
- The chain reference hierarchy is **INPUT** <-- **ufw-before-input** <-- **ufw-user-input**.

#### Solution

The Solution is moving **ufw-before-input** above **REJECT all** [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241021/203760).

1. Write the output of `iptables-save` to a file:
   `iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt`
2. Edit this file with a text editor, move the line you want.
3. Reload the file: `iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.txt`

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http       
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere 
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere 
...

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
...
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere  
...

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8080
```

Comment: this worked for me thatnks

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was solved by setting the rule from

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

That is the only thing that worked, not allowing port 53, allowing dns, etc.

Comment: This worked out for me.