# UFW Allows 22 for IPv4 and IPv6 but SSH Disconnects When Enabling

Tags: kernel, ssh, 18.04, firewall, ufw

`sudo ufw disable` followed by `sudo ufw enable` kicks me out of SSH

DMESG reports

`[UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=30:........ SRC=192.168.1.me DST=192.168.1.server LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15776 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55640 DPT=22 WINDOW=253 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0`

I can log back in without having to change rules via the console (UFW still enabled).

This started after upgrading Xenial (16.04) from kernel 4.4 to 4.15 (HWE). Upgrading to 18.04.1 did not solve the issue.

Versions:

- iptables v1.6.1
- ufw 0.35
- 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

UFW status verbose is (some rules were omitted, but they are all ALLOW)

```
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**Why is this happening, or at least, how to revert to the expected behavior?**

I looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/893080/111533), and I am not sure it applies, but here's /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines


# allow all on loopback
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow dhcp client to work
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

PS: I didn't expect this to "fix" the issue but just for reference I changed the port SSHD listens on (and the corresponding rule) and the problem persists.

Comment: So everything works as it should except that you are momentarily drop from the ssh session when you turn the firewall off then back on?

Comment: yes, momentarily as in it disconnects and I have to connect again. it doesn't "just" stall

Comment: This is very strange because enable/disable via ufw should only come into effect after you reboot. You can check using systemctl status ufw to see that is still running (or not running) when those commands are issued.

Comment: enable/disable on UFW's case is the same as start/stop, in addition to systemctl enable/disable

Comment: Strange that the behaviour is different on your setup. When I issue "sudo ufw disable" that leave the current running ufw session active.

Comment: Every disable is followed by the message "Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup" and vice versa for enable on xenial and bionic, at least.

Comment: This appears to be a kernel regression and seems to have been introduced between kernels 4.13 and 4.14. I am doing a kernel bisection now. It will take a day or two. If any reader already knows the culprit commit, please post here so that I don't waste the time.

Comment: @DougSmythies do you have a bug # where this can be followed?

Comment: No bug number yet, I only just finished the kernel bisection. 4d3a57f23dec59f0a2362e63540b2d01b37afe0a netfilter: conntrack: do not enable connection tracking unless needed. Give me a few hours and I'll write an answer.

Comment: PS: I haven't yet tried to reboot as described at https://askubuntu.com/a/1056204/111533, but I've uninstalled and reinstalled UFW, also tried reset and rebuilding rules

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Background, and bounds for the issue:**

- The issue only occurs when UFW, or iptables, with these ssh allow rules, is enabled and an ssh session is started. i.e. Any SSH session that was started with no iptables at all works fine, but may be subject to random drop outs once the rule set are put in place.
- recall that ufw is merely a front end for iptables.
- The issue is present even with kernel 4.18-rc8.

**What is going on?**

The `sudo ufw allow in port 22` results in the following iptables rules segment:

```
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      16     1553 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
     386   300622 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      15     1068 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
      15     1068 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
```

Upon `sudo ufw disable` followed by `sudo ufw enable`, and even though the ssh connection itself remains fine, the resulting iptables rule set seems to have forgotten the association with that particular connection and therefore classifies any incoming packets as invalid. Somehow the connection tracking table has become confused and the packet is not even considered NEW, but with incorrect flags, nor is it considered part of the existing connection.

Consider a very basic iptables equivalent of what `ufw` is doing. Two scripts, one for clearing the rule set and one for creating it:

```
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# clear_firewall_min 2018.08.10 Ver:0.01
#       clear iptables minimum.
#       Currently for this question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059781/ufw-allows-22-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-but-ssh-disconnects-when-enabling
#
echo "Loading clear_firewall_min version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Set some stuff
#
EXTIF="ens5"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT

# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z

#sleep 10

echo clear_firewall_min $FWVER done.
```

And:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# test_firewall 2018.08.13 Ver:0.01
#       Minimum version of most basic iptables firewall.
#
# test_firewall 2018.08.09 Ver:0.01
#       Most basic iptables firewall.
#       Currently for this question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059781/ufw-allows-22-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-but-ssh-disconnects-when-enabling
#

#sleep 50

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Set some stuff
#
EXTIF="ens5"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
#echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "IINVALID:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

echo "test_firewall_min $FWVER done..." >> /dev/kmsg

sleep 3
```

Resulting in these packets counts after a clear/load cycle with an ssh session that was started after a load cycle:

```
doug@s17:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 3 packets, 220 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      35     6388 LOG        tcp  --  ens5   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "IINVALID:"
      35     6388 DROP       tcp  --  ens5   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
       9      680 ACCEPT     all  --  ens5   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ens5   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 1408 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Notice the 35 invalid packets as I typed on the crippled ssh session terminal, and before PuTTY terminated.

**Why did this stop working, it used to work?**

Because this is 100% repeatable, a kernel bisection was relatively easy, just time consuming. The results were:

```
4d3a57f23dec59f0a2362e63540b2d01b37afe0a is the first bad commit
commit 4d3a57f23dec59f0a2362e63540b2d01b37afe0a
Author: Florian Westphal <fw@strlen.de>
Date:   Fri Jul 28 11:22:04 2017 +0200

    netfilter: conntrack: do not enable connection tracking unless needed

    Discussion during NFWS 2017 in Faro has shown that the current
    conntrack behaviour is unreasonable.

    Even if conntrack module is loaded on behalf of a single net namespace,
    its turned on for all namespaces, which is expensive.  Commit
    481fa373476 ("netfilter: conntrack: add nf_conntrack_default_on sysctl")
    attempted to provide an alternative to the 'default on' behaviour by
    adding a sysctl to change it.

    However, as Eric points out, the sysctl only becomes available
    once the module is loaded, and then its too late.

    So we either have to move the sysctl to the core, or, alternatively,
    change conntrack to become active only once the rule set requires this.

    This does the latter, conntrack is only enabled when a rule needs it.

    Reported-by: Eric Dumazet <edumazet@google.com>
    Signed-off-by: Florian Westphal <fw@strlen.de>
    Signed-off-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso <pablo@netfilter.org>
```

[Link](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/809410/) to the entire commit.

**How to revert to the expected behavior?**

After disabling ufw or clearing the iptables rules set, create a new SSH session. It will survive a subsequent ufw enable, but might be subject to a random drop out at some point.

This issue will be taken upstream at some point, via the related e-mail list.

EDIT: [upstream e-mail thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg55682.html) (contains a work around). Workaround copied here:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal
```

EDIT 2: [upstream proposed patch](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg55775.html) , which I have tested and reported back.

EDIT 3: 2018.11.06: This has stalled upstream, and I haven't had time to pester them. I'll try to get back to it soon.

EDIT 4: 2019.03.17: I can not reliably reproduce this issue with kernel 5.0.

Comment: thank you, great work! does this happen on any 4.13+ kernels or only upgraded from 4.4 ones? and do you think the mitigation mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/a/1056204/111533 could possibly work? I can't be rebooting this machine on trial and error steps...

Comment: The issue persists even with kernel 4.18-rc8. There is a relationship between if the problem will occur or not based on if the queue to any ssh session is empty or not. No, that mitigation is not the solution. I need more time.

Comment: I will mark as answered so that you get the full bounty... dunno if you would still get the full bounty if i let it expire(?). looking fwd to seeing more of your work, thank you!

Comment: O.K. thanks. I have to make some changes to the answer, but don't know when. There are multiple issues here. I am part way through a second kernel bisection, related to iptables only. I'm trying to eliminate UFW from the issue. Things are a bit of a mess (my opinion), and the conntrak tool is basically broken because of the first commit I found. I'll go upstream once I have sufficient detail to do so.

Comment: @Gaia If you don't assign the full bounty then Doug will only get 50% of it **IF** there are two up-votes. Currently there is only one up-vote so I'm adding another in part for 50% bounty assurance but mostly because it's an excellent answer.

Comment: I must add that after a restart I can only SSH in if I log on to the console and disable UFW. Enabling after the disable is ofc optional, but desired, and does not keep me from being able to SSH in.

Comment: @Gaia: by "restart" do you mean re-boot? And is that with UFW enabled? If yes, and yes, that has not been my experience. What does "ofc" mean?

Comment: OFC=Of Course. Restart=Reboot, With UFW enabled, Didn't work. Also uninstalled, rebooted, reset ufw, enabled, re-installed the rules I need, still have to disable once to enable any SSH logins.

Comment: @Gaia: I can only assume your issue is somehow related to some other of your UFW rules. I have sent an upstream e-mail (they don't have a bug system), but I eliminated UFW entirely, and only refer to iptables. Since I am not on that particular e-mail list, and I don't yet see it in the archive, I assume it is being held for moderation. I'll supply a link once available.

Comment: if I have no SSH session established, I disable/enable UFW, then all of sudden I can login w/o changing rules, how could it be related to my rules?

Comment: @Gaia: I can not speculate. All I know is, with only the ssh rules, UFW enabled and then re-boot ssh connection works fine, at least for me. It gets dropped upon a subsequent UFW disable/enable.

Comment: It sounds from the last section as if conntrack was just disabled as the default; so does the OP need instead to write iptables rules with conntrack enabled for the SSH connections?

Comment: @pbhj How do I enable it, I will try

Comment: Given how many ppl this affects do you think it will get backported to 4.15?

Comment: we'll have to see how it plays out. I found a problem with the patch. Version 2 expected soon.

Comment: Any news on this, Doug?

Comment: @Gaia : No. They got me to try a few patches, but there was always a problem. Haven't heard anything for a few weeks now.

Comment: gotcha. instead of the `nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal` workaround i am just setting cron to `ufw disable && ufw enable` upon reboot. this way seems to me less likely to have unintended consequences. at least I can ssh in after a reboot (i dont need to disable ufw from ssh that often)

Comment: any update on this, @DougSmythies?

Comment: @Gaia: No. I'll have to review this, and test the most recent kernel 5.0 (or 5.1-rc1 in a few days).

Comment: @Gaia: If there is any issue still with kernel 5.0, then it is rare and hard to reproduce. If have had SSH sessions dropped, but have not been able to isolate a repeatable way.