# UFW no longer allowing connection when enabled

Tags: networking, vpn, ufw

I have been using openvpn with UFW as a killswitch without issue, but now my internet stops working when I enable UFW after VPN conection is made. Ifconfig shows a tun0. I have been using the following rules:

```
sudo ufw reset
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
sudo ufw enable
```

I always disable UFW, then establish VPN connection, confirm VPN is working, then enable UFW, Then use working VPN connection with the enabled UFW.

But now when I enable the UFW, I don't have access to the net.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or something as I has been working previously without issue. The rules are basic and are as per [GNU/LINUX UFW VPN KILLSWITCH TUTORIAL](https://gist.github.com/Necklaces/18b68e80bf929ef99312b2d90d0cded2) and several other tutorials.

Comment: The issue is on 16.04 and on several computer so I don't think its a hardware issue. The UFW works perfectly when I reinstall ubuntu and set everything up, but when i download the updates and restart the computer, then  the UFW wont work

Comment: See if this [might](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059781/ufw-allows-22-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-but-ssh-disconnects-when-enabling/1064533#1064533) be related. And try the workaround: `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal`

Comment: Thanks Doug, but that didn't fix it. Do you think it might be a bug on UFW end?

Comment: @mel-94 UFW is doing exactly what you told it to do; drop all outgoing traffic except on tun0. Now, how do you expect to reach the VPN-server?

Answer (score 0):

The rules you set deny all outgoing, but allow on tun0.

But the VPN traffic has to be allowed out on a real interface, either wlan or ethernet! Thus the tunnel will cease working the moment you enable the firewall, as the packets can not leave the local machine.

Remember that VPN works by creating a virtual interface on your computer. It takes traffic from this interface, encrypts it, and transmits it to a remote VPN server. This transmission **has** to be allowed.

Add a firewall rule that allows VPN out to the VPN server's IP address, and relevant port. Typically this is 1194 for OpenVPN. This is mentioned in step five of the tutorial you're linking to.

Comment: Thank you Vidarlo,  but it says step 5 is optional and not needed if I disable UFW to enable VPN connection then enable UFW.   "At this point you're technically done, but with this setup you would need to disable UFW every time OpenVPN needed to connect to your VPN and then re-enable UFW when it has connected"

Comment: Try what I suggest before you dismiss it. UDP is connectionless, and a deny rule will filter future packets. TCP rules will likely not affect established connections.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, the easiest thing to do is to set

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

in `/etc/default/ufw`

Comment: That's terrible advice!

Comment: @guntbert Is the answer true and valid? Yes

If you want to contribute positively you can share a link about the risks.