# why is /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count in Ubuntu 22?

Tags: networking

In older versions of Ubuntu I was using /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count to see how many connections were active. I did this because I noticed that with lots of traffic if there are too many connections and they would get dropped. This would also interfere with traffic on the local network.
In Ubuntu 22, this value is always 0. Has this moved somewhere else or do I need to configure something so I can monitor this again?

Comment: Keep in mind that since Ubuntu 21.10 the default backend is nftables.  There is tooling that makes `iptables` actually speak `nftables`, but the underlying 'netfilter' components may not be being used if nftables is present on the system (which I believe it is in modern Ubuntu as the true backend)

Comment: @ThomasWard : Oh yes, thank you. I forgot I have my system configured to use legacy iptables. Perhaps the OP could get enough information from the `ss -s` command.

Answer (score 0):

For the file location to be defined you would need to have the `nf_conntrack` module loaded, which it isn't by default.

```
doug@s19:~$ lsmod | grep conn
doug@s19:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
cat: /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count: No such file or directory
```

One can force load the module:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo modprobe nf_conntrack
[sudo] password for doug:
doug@s19:~$ lsmod | grep conn
nf_conntrack          196608  0
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         12288  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              12288  4 nf_conntrack,btrfs,nf_tables,raid456
doug@s19:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
0
```

But then nothing is using it, so the count is always 0, as you have discovered. But if one loads an iptables (or nftables) rule set that have some connection tracking rules, then the count is used:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ lsmod | grep conn
xt_conntrack           12288  6
nf_conntrack          196608  1 xt_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         12288  1 nf_conntrack
x_tables               65536  5 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_LOG,xt_tcpudp,ip_tables
libcrc32c              12288  4 nf_conntrack,btrfs,nf_tables,raid456
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
2
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$
```

Here is an example simple iptables rule set that I used for the above non 0 count. My test server is local only, hence the low connection count. On my external facing server I typically have 100's of connections in various states.

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat test_firewall_min
#!/bin/sh
#
# test_firewall_min 2021.10.04 Ver:0.01
#       update interface name for s19.
#
# test_firewall 2018.08.13 Ver:0.01
#       Minimum version of most basic iptables firewall.
#
# test_firewall 2018.08.09 Ver:0.01
#       Most basic iptables firewall.
#       Currently for this question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059781/ufw-allows-22-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-but-ssh-disconnects-when-enabling
#

#sleep 50

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Set some stuff
#
EXTIF="br0"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
#echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "IINVALID:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

echo "test_firewall_min $FWVER done..." >> /dev/kmsg
```

And I get this, after logging via ssh a couple more times:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo conntrack -L
tcp      6 299 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.111.136 dst=192.168.111.122 sport=22 dport=56246 src=192.168.111.122 dst=192.168.111.136 sport=56246 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
tcp      6 431975 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.111.122 dst=192.168.111.136 sport=50470 dport=22 src=192.168.111.136 dst=192.168.111.122 sport=22 dport=50470 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
tcp      6 431942 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.111.122 dst=192.168.111.136 sport=50456 dport=22 src=192.168.111.136 dst=192.168.111.122 sport=22 dport=50456 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
conntrack v1.4.5 (conntrack-tools): 3 flow entries have been shown.
```

Comment: I already had these modules loaded. nf_conntrack_count was present but 0.
`maarten@primo:~$ lsmod | grep conn
nf_conntrack_netlink    61440  0
nf_conntrack          204800  1 nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_tables
nfnetlink              24576  3 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables`

Comment: But what do I need to add so the connections get counted? I suppose it's the TCP connections I'm after since I was also tweaking net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established to get the connections down.

Comment: Any iptables rule that uses connection tracking will activate the module, and load it if is not already. I'll try to edit my answer with an example shortly. I use 36000 for `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established` and 65 for `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait` and 3600 for `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait`

Comment: Reminder that legacy `netfilter` components have been replaced since 21.10 with `nftables` backends.  `iptables` was rewritten with `nftables` compat to be a frontend that can work with `nftables` on the backend, so these `proc sys` items, etc. won't work out of the box